# How to get this link to start in another folder?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, shortcut, lnk

I have a batch script that creates a vbs that creates a shortcut (complicated I know), however the problem is that it launches the program where the shortcut is located. Any way to make it start in C:\users\Public\Settings\ where the exe is? Thanks everyone!

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET LinkName=ITCMD-Notifier-Settings
SET Esc_LinkDest=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\!LinkName!.lnk
SET Esc_LinkTarget=C:\users\Public\ITCMD\Settings\ITCMD Notifier Settings.exe
SET cSctVBS=CreateShortcut.vbs
SET LOG=".\%~N0_runtime.log"
((
  echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^) 
  echo sLinkFile = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkDest!"^)
  echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^) 
  echo oLink.TargetPath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkTarget!"^)
  echo oLink.Save
)1>!cSctVBS!
cscript //nologo .\!cSctVBS!
DEL !cSctVBS! /f /q
)1>>!LOG! 2>>&1
```

Comment: place `echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "C:\users\Public\Settings"` before `echo oLink.Save` Also is best practice enclose both var name and var content within quotes  as in `SET "Esc_LinkTarget=C:\users\Public\ITCMD\Settings\ITCMD Notifier Settings.exe"`

Comment: shouldn't it be `C:\users\Public\Settings\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 )1>!cSctVBS!
SET "originaldir=!CD!"
PUSHD %Esc_LinkTarget%
cscript //nologo "!originaldir!\!cSctVBS!"
POPD
DEL !cSctVBS! /f /q
```

No guarantee, naturally. Should save the original directory name, then switch to the executable's directory, then switch back before deleting the file.

I've included quotes around the `cscript` target in case the current directory contains separators. I've no notion of how `cscript` would see that...

Another possibility would be to switch to the executable's directory first just before the `echo`es which create the VBS file, then pop back after deleting that file.